# ASP.NET MVC Usermanager SendEmailAsync: How to change sender email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 with Identity 2, theres a file called IdentityConfig.cs which has EmailSerive that I have implemented like this:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage("info@mydomain.com", message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body))
            {
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup, I am able to send user emails by calling this method on UserManager:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, emailSubject, emailBody);
```

So far so good, but Id want the email to be sent from different senders depending on the subject. For instance, account registration/reset password will have sender account@mydomain.com, information inquiry emails will have sender info@mydomain.com, sales/order placement should have sender sales@mydomain.com.

Unfortunately, the method SendEmailAsync has no way to set the sender, and I have no idea how to achieve this in the EmailService either. Can anyone help with this problem? Is there a way to add an extension method to UserManager or EmailSerivce so I can optionally specify a different sender?

Comment: You can't use UserManager. You'll have to call your email provider direct.

Comment: @GHDevOps How to call email provider directly?

Comment: Depends on the provider. I'm sure c# has a client for it. We use SendGrid so just creating a new instance of the client and use that. If you're using MS products, you might have to user interop.

Comment: We are using the internal STMP though, not sure how much difference it makes. Still, is it really impossible to add an extension method to UserManager or EmailService to achieve this behavior?

Comment: very easy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?view=net-5.0 probably the hardest thing is tracking down your server name!

Comment: You seem to be setting the sender address with a literal value when you instantiate your `MailMessage` instance.  Why not just change this to a variable and set the value of this variable (conditionally based on subject) before you instantiate `MailMessage`?  IOW why do you need `SendEmailAsync()` to provide a parameter for **sender** when you can set it via `MailMessage()` ?

Comment: @DavidTansey Sure I can set this as a variable but the variable has to come from somewhere. Id like to be able to actually set the sender from client code, rather than from this SendAsync() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am in your place I would put all my emails in the **web.config** file and access it in a private method in the **EmailService** class that returns relevant email based on the subject and then call this method at the place of email parameter. e.g:

```
public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message) 
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {   
        //calling getEmail() instead of email
        using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage(getEmail(message.Subject),
    message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body))
        {
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}

private string getEmail(string subject) 
{
    var emails = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Emails"];
    string[] emailAddresses = emails.Split(',');
    //your logic here
    return email;
}
```